# Indicator to tell me I already flagged a question

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I've been flagging a lot lately, and it's harmless for me to reflag the same question twice because the second time it just says I already flagged it, but all the same I find it bothersome that there's no way for me to tell if I already flagged a Q or not.

Would be a nice feature for a Q to have a little red flag or something to indicate to me that I already flagged it.

Comment: Technically you can flag a post as many times as you want, but from the second time and onwards you can only use the custom flag.

Comment: @YannisRizos all the more reason an indicator would be helpful..